# Flex with Presentation model

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, videodisplay, presentation-model

How to control videodisplay functions like videodisplay.stop, pause(), close etc from the presentation model?
But I need to control it from Presentation model.
Custom events is not my option, as that is costly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a peek at my [code behind approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10835854/flash-builder-4-6-code-behind-approach/10841887#10841887): you could just give the model an id and call methods on it. But i really don't think custom events are too costly.

Answer (score 0):

I used the Binding tag to solve a similar problem (calling centerAt on an ESRI Map) :

```
<fx:Binding source="model.videoState" destination="videoState"/>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        private function set videoState(value:String):void
        {
            // do whatever is to be done
```

This avoid custom events, and preserve the pattern : your presentation model does not know about the video display.